# keyboard mouse doesn't work after KDE desktop boot on ubuntu server

Tags: server, keyboard, mouse, kde, xrdp

I have installed ubuntu server with xrdp and installed KDE desktop with `sudo apt install kde-standard`. I can login with the local machine to the server and the kde session starts and my local mouse and keyboard work in the session. However, the mouse and keyboard on the server machine do not work after KDE boot. It works when I want to enter the machine BIOS setup but after I see the KDE login page, nothing works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future readers: After a lot of experiments I found the solution:

**Install kde desktop first then install xrdp!**

Comment: I reinstalled kde-plasma-desktop on local machine and now i cannot use my keyboard amd mouse